# How to revert back to an old commit in remote after a wrongful merge?

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-merge, git-push

I am using BitBucket as my remote repo. One of my training team members mistakenly pushed another branch into the `master`. Now, this is how my repo looks like.

[image]

Well, he made a huge mess. I want to revert this to the commit `4f9ff` which has the message "New model classes added". In my PC, the last commit of `master` is `4f9ff` as well.

FYI, this is how my local repo looks like.

[image]

How can I revert the remote repo to commit `4f9ff`?

I tried `git push --force origin 4f9ff27:master;`   and it did nothing in remote.

Comment: Since your local and remote are pointing to same commit but in reality, the remote master is ahead of your local commit. Try `git fetch --all` and this will update your origin/master and then you can do a force push

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `git push --force` command you tried, but you need it to be slightly different:

```
git push --force origin 4f9ff27:master
```

(what you tried) has to read instead:

```
git push --force origin 4f9ff27:refs/heads/master
```

But you can much more simply just run:

```
git push --force origin master
```

*Before you do this*, read on.  Note that the Bitbucket server may still refuse to do this at all, depending on what permissions you give yourself, too.

First, Git is really all about *commits*.  Those hash IDs, whether abbreviated (as in `4f9ff27`) or spelled out in full (they'll be 40 characters long when spelled out in full), are the "true names" for the commits.  Those "true names" work in *every* Git repository, as long as the Git repository actually *has the commit*.

The thing about these big ugly hash IDs is that they're quite useless to *humans*.  We're not going to around memorizing that `4f9ff27` is the latest `master` commit today, and then tomorrow memorize that `fadbabe` is the latest commit, and then on Tuesday that it's now `dadcafe` or whatever.  We just want to say `master` and get *the latest commit for `master`, whatever that is*.

So that's what a branch name is and does for us.  The *name* `master`, in *each clone*—each one has *its own*—is "the latest commit" on `master`.  There's your clone, on your laptop, that has your `master`, and your team member's clone, on his laptop, that has *his* `master`—his is almost certainly using `4af43...` as *his* latest—and there's one over on Bitbucket.

The Git repository over on Bitbucket is not special in any way except one: you, and this other guy, and maybe several more people, *think of it as special*.  But in fact, each of your own Git repositories is just as good as the one on Bitbucket, or maybe even better, because it has *your* commits in it.  The Bitbucket one is only special *because you think of it that way*.

So, just be careful *when* you think of it that way.  Remember that your commits are *yours*, and your *branch names* are yours, and your own Git repository is its own thing.

What you do when you run `git push`, `git fetch`, and/or `git pull` is to *connect* your Git software, working with your Git repository to another Git-software-and-repository pair.  Having connected your Git—your software and repository as a pair—to their Git, you can now:

- give them any new commits you made, that they don't have; and
- ask them to set some of their branch names.

This is a `git push` operation.

Or, you can:

- get from them any new commits *they* have that you don't.

This is a `git fetch` operation.  This won't set any of *your* branch names, because `git fetch` *never touches any of your branches*.

The bad part about not updating any of *your* branch names is ... well, names are *how we find the commits*, because we (humans) are bad at random-looking crud like `4f9ff27`.  So when `git fetch` gets commits *from them*, your Git will copy their *branch* names, but *change them*.  You will get *remote-tracking names* instead.  If they have `master`, and you call their Git `origin`, your Git will create or update your own `origin/master`.

**In other words, there is a bit of asymmetry here.**  When you use `git fetch`, you get new commits *from* them, and your Git then creates or updates *remote-tracking names*.  This does not disturb any branch names in any way.  (The new commits you get from Bitbucket probably got there because someone used `git push`, so they may be commits made by several different people.)

When you use `git push`, though, you send them *your* new commits, and then you ask them—Bitbucket—to create or update one of their *branch* names.

#### Branch names start with `refs/heads/`

Normally, you'll do:

```
git push origin master
```

or:

```
git push origin feature/xyz
```

or whatever.  This `git push` request uses the *branch name* you have on *your side*—`master` or `feature/xyz`—to *find the commits to send*.  Your Git then sends those commits to Bitbucket.  (They have, at this stage, an opportunity to reject the commits outright.  I don't use Bitbucket but it's worth noting that GitHub will reject incoming commits at this point if any one file inside any one of the commits exceeds 100 MB.  Mostly this doesn't really affect anything yet, though.)  Then—once the commits are across—your Git says: *Now, if it's OK please set your name _______ (fill in a name) to ______ (fill in a hash ID)*.  The *name* your Git sends here is the *same branch name you used to select the commit to send*.

Internally within Git, *branch* names start with `refs/heads/`.  This means your `master` is really `refs/heads/master`.  *Remote-tracking names* like `origin/master` start with `refs/remotes/` instead, so that `origin/master` is really `refs/remotes/origin/master`.  Tag names live in `refs/tags/`, e.g., `refs/tags/v2.1`.  Most of the time you don't have to think about this as you just use a branch or tag name on your side, for `git push`, and don't use anything at all for `git fetch`.  For the fetch case, Git uses the *same name* on both sides.

When you use the colon syntax `4f9ff27:<name>`, however, you're telling your Git: *use the thing on the left to find the commits to send/push, but ask them to set the name on the right*.  When you do that, you *must spell out the full name*.  So that's why `4f9ff27:master` does not suffice.

When they get this nice polite request of the form *please, if it's OK, set a branch name*, they will check whether it's OK.  It *is* OK in plain Git if:

- it's a new branch, or
- it only causes *new commits to become find-able* on that branch.

When you need to use `git push --force` or `git push --force-with-lease` or similar, this is because your non-forced push is failing the second test: you're telling the other Git to set the branch name in such a way that some commit(s) *won't be findable* in *their* repository using the branch name you're telling them to set.

**Before you do that, if those commits are valuable, it's a good idea to make sure that someone can still find them.**  It doesn't really matter *who* can find them, but *someone* needs to be able to do that.

If all those commits are definitely find-able by some other branch name, you are good to go, and can go ahead and `git push --force master`.  If not, you should make sure that the other guy *keeps his commits*, and/or set some *other* branch name over in the Bitbucket repository so that the Bitbucket Git will remember those commits, under this other branch name.  For instance, you could run:

```
git fetch origin
git push origin origin/master:refs/heads/bob
```

to make the name `refs/heads/bob` on `origin` (Bitbucket) remember the commit hash ID that they had in their `master` at the time your `git fetch` ran.<sup>1</sup>  Now you can `git push --force-with-lease origin master`.<sup>2</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>The phrase *at the time your `git fetch` ran* here is deliberate: if someone is actively pushing to Bitbucket, your `git fetch` will get the commits that are there when your `git fetch` runs.  It's possible that seconds, or even just milliseconds, later, someone *adds ten new commits*.  You won't have them yet!  There are a lot of ways to handle this, but in smaller shops, someone will sometimes just yell out (and/or post on Slack) "don't push to master, we're fixing it" and then a few minutes later "all fixed, you can push again".

<sup>2</sup>The `--force-with-lease` option is a gentler variant of `--force`.  Plain `--force` says to the Bitbucket Git: *Set your `refs/heads/master` to `4f9ff27` now!*  The `--force-with-lease` option says: *I think your `refs/heads/master` is ______ (fill in the blank via origin/master); if so, set it to `4f9ff27` now!*  This handles that race I mentioned in footnote 1: if someone *has* pushed, you get a chance to try again.

---

#### A short aside about `git pull`

Many people like to use `git pull` as the opposite of `git push`, but it isn't (opposite, that is).  It's `git fetch` that is as close as one gets to an opposite.

What `git pull` does is:

1. run `git fetch`; then
2. run a second Git command.

That *second* command is usually `git merge`, though you can make it run `git rebase` instead, even by default.  The point of the *second* command is simple: `git fetch` never affects any of *your* branches, but often, the reason you ran `git fetch` was so that you could affect some of your branches.  That requires additional commands.

Pull rolls together the fetch plus *one* additional command.  If you want or need more than one—I often do—or *no* additional command, it makes more sense to run `fetch` first, then run your commands (plural), or do nothing.  In this case you *don't* want your Git to update *your* `master`.  You want your Git to leave your `master` alone.  So you want `git fetch`, not `git pull`.

#### Protected branches

Git, in its basic raw for, has *no* branch protection.  Hosting web sites like GitHub, GitLab, and Bitbucket add on the idea of protected branches.

A *protected branch* limits who can do what with the branch name.  The precise details depend on the hosting service.  See what protections Bitbucket offer for the name `master`.  You may be able to stop anyone except yourself from pushing directly to it.  You may be able to stop anyone *including* yourself from pushing directly to it, even with `--force`, so be careful with these settings, but if you're the admin, you should be able to give yourself permission even if you accidentally already removed your own permission.

#### Conclusion

The force-push you're trying to do is mostly right.  Make sure the other guy's commits won't be lost entirely—save them on your own laptop for instance, with `git fetch` and a branch name of your own, and/or by creating another branch on Bitbucket if appropriate.  You can skip this step *if* you're sure that those other commits *are* available via other branch names (i.e., that the other guy didn't do a merge and then delete).

*Then*, once you're sure it's safe, `git push --force`.  If you've prohibited Bitbucket from allowing *any* force pushes, even from yourself, go give yourself permission to force-push at least long enough to get this done.